# How to set the column number in `awk -F@ '{ print $1 }` with a command line argument in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file, `script.sh`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F@ '{ print $1 } file.csv
```

This prints column 1 of `file.csv`.

I'd like to be able to run `script.sh` with an argument such as `./script.sh 3` which means it will instead print column 3. Or `./script.sh 10`, which means it will instead print column 10.

How can I can the command line argument to AWK in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
awk -v i=$1 -F@ '{print $i}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.(have added usage in script too in case a user doesn't pass it, user should get message for it)

```
cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
val="$1"
if [[ -n "$val" ]]
then
    awk -v value="$val" -F'@' '{print $value}' file.csv
else
    echo "Usage: Please pass an argument to print a specific field of line while running script as ./script.sh 1"
fi
```